# Are custom attribute bindings possible with Vue templates?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to bind a custom attribute value in my Vue template. How can I do this?

(EDIT: The following code actually binds correctly. A third party library (Foundation) was interfering with the binding. Leaving the question up as it may be useful to others.

```
<template>
    <span v-bind="{ 'aria-controls': inputControlId }"></span>
    <input v-bind="{ 'id': inputControlId }">
</template>

<script lang="ts">

    import Vue from 'vue';
    import Component from 'vue-class-component';

    @Component
    export default class Slider extends Vue {
       inputControlId = "TheBourneId";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The common syntax for [binding attributes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes) is

```
<template>
    <span v-bind:aria-controls="inputControlId"></span>
    <input v-bind:id="inputControlId">
</template>
```

There is also a [shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand).

```
<template>
    <span :aria-controls="inputControlId"></span>
    <input :id="inputControlId">
</template>
```

You can bind [multiple properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) at once using the syntax in your question, it's just not commonly used outside `class` or `style`, especially for single attributes.

It sounds like the real issue was your CSS framework.

Comment: Thanks! After trying a few variations of this I figured out that a 3rd party library (Foundation) was interfering with the binding in my case. My example code actually works as intended, but using your syntax seems better. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: @pulekies You're right there is a third syntax, which you are using, but it is primarily intended when you are binding multiple properties at the same time. I'll update the answer.